# ng repeat does not return variable from JSON file

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following html code that belongs to a template in AngularJS framework:

```
   <ul class="sb-parentlist">
    <h1 class={{headerClass}}> Popular</h1><div data-ng-repeat="data in data track by $index">
    <li>
        <span class="sb-text-title"  href="#" ng-click="openFaq = ! openFaq"><b>{{data[$index].faq.frage |translate}}</b></span>
                    <span ng-show="openFaq" class="sb-text">
                         <br>
                         {{data[$index].faq.antwort |translate}}
                    </span>
    </li>
        </div>
    </ul>
```

I am getting the number of "li" elements on my browser correctly on printing the results, but the variables are not defined as they should be, blank entries appearing.
here is the JSON entry:

```
   {

      "faq":
        {"frage":"HB_START_FAQ_Q",
          "antwort":"HB_START_FAQ_A"}
      ,
      "screencast":"HB_START_SCREENCAST"
    },
    {

      "faq":
        {"frage":"HB_START_FAQ_Q_1",
          "antwort":"HB_START_FAQ_A_1"}
      ,
      "screencast":"HB_START_SCREENCAST_1"
    },
    {

      "faq":
        {"frage":"HB_START_FAQ_Q_2",
          "antwort":"HB_START_FAQ_A_2"}
     ,
      "screencast":"HB_START_SCREENCAST_2"
    },
    {

      "faq":
        {"frage":"HB_START_FAQ_Q_3",
          "antwort":"HB_START_FAQ_A_3"}
     ,
      "screencast":"HB_START_SCREENCAST_3"
    }
```

I am interested to get the nested item. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `data` is ambiguous between the collection name and the item being iterated over - change your `ngRepeat` syntax:

```
data-ng-repeat="item in data track by $index"
```

And use `item[$index]`. Im not entirely sure why you aren't just doing `data.faq` - you need to select by the `$index`